# After installing an optical drive in a pc ubuntu refuses to boot

Tags: boot, dvd, cd

After installing an optical drive in a pc ubuntu refuses to boot. I get a black screen, no error message. If I remove the drive it works again. Booting with recovery mode freezes up too.

[image]

ps: its not a boot order issue I'm booting from my ssd, it happens after ubuntu starts booting. The drive isn't defective booting from it works.

Comment: This means that the first boot device is your optical drive and it contains some bootable media that doesn't work. Your goal is unclear.

Comment: Edit your BIOS and move optical drive to bottom of boot order.

Comment: my optical drive is not the first boot device and it does not contain any media bootable or not. as the picture shows I am able to boot into recovery mode from grub but it freezes at a certain point.

Comment: Maybe it's defective? Have you tried it in a different computer?

Comment: The drive is working I'v tried to put a bootable disc in it and it worked in this computer.

Comment: try bootoption `uas_blacklist=uas`  the boot hangs by initializing your cardreader, an it loads module uas before.